# Accessing CSS class using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, styles, stylesheet

How can i access the style declaration of an element specified using external or embedded stylesheet.For ex: how to access the width property of an element which is defined in an embeded stylesheet  using the id selector..
I know CSSRules object can do this...But it is browser  dependent.For ex:in chrome ,the object is null...So what is the browser independent way to do this?

Comment: To be clear: are you trying to access the rule(s) that apply to the element, or are you trying to find out the final style that applies to a particular element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really browser dependent... I have a bit of code which I use to make an auto-expand text area, adapted from code found [there](https://web.archive.org/web/20131003073445/http://webdesign.torn.be/tutorials/javascript/prototype/auto-expand-contract-textarea/).

Note, the `$` function here is from [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/).

```
function getStyleFromCss(el, style) {
    /* Hack required by IE */
    var value = $(el).getStyle(style);
    if (!value) {
        /* For other browsers. Actually this equals 'window'. Use that
         *  if Opera fails on you. */
        if(document.defaultView) {
            value = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).
                getPropertyValue(style);
            // for IE
        } else if(el.currentStyle) {
            value = el.currentStyle[style];
        }
    }
    if(value.length > 0){
        /* if the value returned has the word px in it, we check for
         *  the letter x */
        if (value.charAt(value.length-1) == "x") {
            value = parseInt(value.substring(0, value.length-2));
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

The `getStyle()` function from Prototype is defined this way, you should be able to easily adapt it to your needs.

```
getStyle: function(element, style) {
  element = $(element);
  style = style == 'float' ? 'cssFloat' : style.camelize();
  var value = element.style[style];
  if (!value || value == 'auto') {
    var css = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null);
    value = css ? css[style] : null;
  }
  if (style == 'opacity') return value ? parseFloat(value) : 1.0;
  return value == 'auto' ? null : value;
},
```

Comment: You don't include the code for either `$()` or for `getStyle()` or for `getPropertyValue()`.  How would one use this from plain javascript?

Comment: I gave the definition for getStyle. getPropertyValue() is DOM stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where IE before IE9 and all other browsers do it differently.  To get the current style on an object including whatever is applied to the object from stylesheets, you could use something like this:

```
function getStyle(el, cssprop) {
    if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle)
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)[cssprop];
    else //IE
        return el.currentStyle[cssprop];
}
```

Comment: Just a question: is document.defaultView needed (first time seeing it)? Are the other options instead of defaultView?

Comment: Thank you. If you delete your second else, I will upvote your answer.